# Actionscript loop sound based on Timer

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to loop a sound based on a time IN Flash CC.

Basically I want the sound to loop as long as the time is greater than 0.

This is what I have come up with so far which seems to just lock up the debugger.

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
var s:soundEffect = new soundEffect();
var time = 15;
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,15)
myTimer.start();
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandle)

function timerHandle(e:TimerEvent){
txt_Timer.text = time;
while(time>0){
    s.play()}
    time --;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop is build in feature.

```
//Simple loop
var sound:SoundEffect = new SoundEffect();
var playChannel:SoundChannel = sound.play(0, int.MAX_VALUE);

//Finish loop after 1 second
var sound:SoundEffect = new SoundEffect();
var playChannel:SoundChannel = sound.play(0, int.MAX_VALUE);
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 1); //Stop loop after 1 second
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onCompleteTimer);
timer.start();

function onCompleteTimer(e:TimerEvent):void {
    playChannel.stop();
}
```